# get the most recently hired employee using dictionary & tuple

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a structure which looks like this in C#

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Tuple<DateTime, string>> tmp = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Tuple<DateTime, string>>();
```

1st Tuple takes a composite key of empid, deptid.
2nd tuple is hiredate & emp name

1st record in the dictionary looks like this:

```
DateTime dt = "2011-01-02 00:00:00.000";//hiredate of employee
tmp.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(Convert.ToInt32(empid), Convert.ToInt32(deptid)), new Tuple<DateTime, string>(dt, "AMy"));
```

2nd record in dictionary

```
DateTime dt2 = "2011-09-09 00:00:00.000";//hiredate of employee
    tmp.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(Convert.ToInt32(anotherempid), Convert.ToInt32(deptid)), new Tuple<DateTime, string>(dt2, "Cathy"));
```

There are several such entries in the dictionary. How can I find the maxhiredate of each department using this dictionary?

Thanks
MR

Comment: Why does the key include the department ID?  Can an employee be associated with more than one department?  (And can the employee have a different hire date associated with each department?)

Comment: @phoog, in our db one employee can be associated with many departments and yes, they have different hire date associated with each dept.

Comment: In that case I am glad I decided to ask "why" rather than following my first impulse, which was to say "you shouldn't" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var result = tmp
            .GroupBy(x => x.Key.Item2)
            .Select(g => new
            {
                DepartmentId = g.Key,
                MaxDate = g.Max(x => x.Value.Item1)
            });
```

but I would use a custom class instead of `Tuple`

Comment: can u help me with writing that function in that class which compares dates. I created the class and made a list of that class and added each data point. I am not sure how to compare.